# Lookup data in Relation database from Hadoop side

Tags: hadoop, data-warehouse, etl

I am converting SSIS solution to Hadoop for ETL processing in the data-warehouse.

My expected system:
ETL - landing & staging (Hadoop) ----put-data---> Data-warehouse(MySQL)

The problem is: in transform phrase, I need to lookup data in MySQL from hadoop side (pig or mapreduce job). There are 2 solutions:
  **1st:** Clone all tables need to lookup from MySQL into Hadoop. It means that we need to maintain data from 2 places.
  **2nd:** query directly to MySQL. I am worried about many connections come to MySQL server.

What is solution/best practise for this problem? Are there any other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to have some representation of your dimensional tables in Hadoop. Depending on the way how you do ETL of the dimension data, you might actually have them as a side effect of the ETL.

Are you planning to store the most granular fact data in MySQL? I my experience, Hive + Hadoop beat realational databases when it comes to storing and analyzing the fact data. If you need a realtime access to the results of the queries, you then can "cache" the summary results by storing them in MySQL.